# How to change my font size and style in android action bar

Tags: android

I changed my `ActionBar` title font color using this:

```
actionBar.setTitle( Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'    >Android </font>"));
```

How to change my font `size` and `style`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can do what you want to customize the ActionBar. It must be done through the Theme. You can do something like this :

```
<style name="Theme.YourTheme" parent="android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.YourTheme.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

    <style name="Theme.YourTheme.Styled.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.Viadeo.Styled.YourTheme.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.YourTheme.Styled.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```css
$ grep ActionBar platforms/android-11/data/res/values/*
```

And than in your styles.xml you can implement this :

```css
<style name="TextAppearance.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
       parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle"
       parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
</style>

[…]

<style name="TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?textColorSecondary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I get this erro                                                                                        error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance'.   @karan khurana

Comment: @chantishruthi Your compile SDK version must match the support library's major version. 
for example : If you are using version 23 of the support library, you need to compile against version 23 of the Android SDK.